# Debugging simple program

Tags: python, python-3.x

We were given a small program to debug and I am stuck in the last piece of the puzzle. It's a grading system program.

A number below 0 or above 100 should result in an error and ask the user for the input again.

I am stuck on this one. Can anybody help?

```
# This program converts a numeric grade to an alpha grade

input_bool = False

while not input_bool:
    input_grade = int(input("Please enter the grade you wish to convert (0-100).\n"))
    if (input_grade >= 0 ) or (input_grade <= 100):
        input_bool = True


    output_grade = ""

    if input_grade >= 0 and input_grade <= 34:
        output_grade = "F"

    elif input_grade >= 35 and input_grade <= 39:
        output_grade = "MF"

    elif input_grade >= 40 and input_grade <= 49: 
        output_grade = "D"

    elif input_grade >= 50 and input_grade <= 59: 
        output_grade = "C"

    elif input_grade >= 60 and input_grade <= 69: 
        output_grade = "B"

    elif input_grade >= 70 and input_grade <= 79: 
        output_grade = "A-"
    
    elif input_grade >= 80 and input_grade <= 89: 
        output_grade = "A"
    
    elif input_grade >= 90 and input_grade <= 100:
        output_grade = "A+"


    print(f"{input_grade} = {output_grade}.")
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. What do you need help with exactly? Like, what have you tried, and where are you stuck? For tips, see [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/4518341) and [ask] in general.

Comment: If it's any help, we have this guide: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved it try to see this code:

```
def calc():

    again_or_not = input("Do you want to play [Y/N]: ")

    if again_or_not == "n":
        print("Good luck, see you soon")

    elif again_or_not == "y":
            # This program converts a numeric grade to an alpha grade

        input_bool = False

        while not input_bool:
            input_grade = int(input("Please enter the grade you wish to convert (0-100).\n"))
            if (input_grade >= 0 ) or (input_grade <= 100):
                input_bool = True


            output_grade = ""

            if input_grade >= 0 and input_grade <= 34:
                output_grade = "F"

            elif input_grade >= 35 and input_grade <= 39:
                output_grade = "MF"

            elif input_grade >= 40 and input_grade <= 49: 
                output_grade = "D"

            elif input_grade >= 50 and input_grade <= 59: 
                output_grade = "C"

            elif input_grade >= 60 and input_grade <= 69: 
                output_grade = "B"

            elif input_grade >= 70 and input_grade <= 79: 
                output_grade = "A-"
            
            elif input_grade >= 80 and input_grade <= 89: 
                output_grade = "A"
            
            elif input_grade >= 90 and input_grade <= 100:
                output_grade = "A+"


        print(f"{input_grade} = {output_grade}.")
        again_or_not2 = input("Do you want to try again [Y/N]: ")
        if again_or_not2 == "n":
            print("Good luck, see you soon")
        else:
            calc()

calc()
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
if (input_grade >= 0) or (input_grade <= 100):
    input_bool = True
```

only checks for one condition to be true and passes to the next line.
In order to check whether the number is in between 0 and 100, you have to use the `and` operator.

Also you can add check for `if not input_bool:` then `continue` as to avoid extra checking of conditions since it isn't even under 0-100.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input_bool = False


while not input_bool:
    input_grade = int(input("Please enter the grade you wish to convert (0-100).\n"))
    if (input_grade >= 0) or (input_grade <= 100):
        input_bool = False

        output_grade = "Error"

    if 0 <= input_grade <= 34:
        output_grade = "F"

    elif 35 <= input_grade <= 39:
        output_grade = "MF"

    elif 40 <= input_grade <= 49:
        output_grade = "D"

    elif 50 <= input_grade <= 59:
        output_grade = "C"

    elif 60 <= input_grade <= 69:
        output_grade = "B"

    elif 70 <= input_grade <= 79:
        output_grade = "A-"

    elif 80 <= input_grade <= 89:
        output_grade = "A"

    elif 90 <= input_grade <= 100:
        output_grade = "A+"

    print(f"{input_grade} = {output_grade}.")
```